# How to start GUI from command line?

Tags: boot, command-line, gui

I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit on my machine. But when I switch on the computer, I get command line:

```
Ubuntu 12.04 LTS COMP-1245 tty1
```

And it prompts for username and password. Once I provide my username and password, it authenticates login and then displays a link to documentation.

Now, how can I start GUI? I'm stuck at command line.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

If you tried the command `startx`, but the error `command not found` was returned, then to install a graphical desktop, in case it is not installed, you would type this:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: Thanks that did it. But why was it not installed while installing the OS itself?

Comment: @MrGhimire It should've been. Are you sure you didn't install with the minimal or server CD? You did say you used the desktop CD, but I don't see how that could've installed Ubuntu without gnome.

Comment: @MrGhimire The minimal CD has a menu that asks if you'd like to install extra packages. Among these are ubuntu-desktop, as well a couple other desktops. Select it and make sure to press space on it, then enter to continue. If you just press enter, it'll skip it.

Comment: (On my VMware player) Is said `ubuntu-desktop is already the newest version.` after reboot it is again opening in command line.

Answer (score 32):

Try to use `startx` in your tty , if it does not work on one terminal try  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F6</kbd> in order to switch a new tty

Comment: This brings up a background image, and if I right click I get a menu containing "New Folder" , "New Document" etc but nothing useful.  I don't get any kind of usable desktop, no dock, not menu bar, nothing.

Comment: I get a Background Image, a green bird in Lubuntu 20_04.

Answer (score 9):

I have had the same problem. The solution is to install `X.org` and the Ubuntu Desktop. Also, don't forget the build-essential packages:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

You might have to install `X.org` separately, but also take advantage of this command line because (for my situation) Ubuntu kept trying to use my display port.

Comment: Why is `build-essential` needed? It is a tool helping the compilation of programs. While it is, for a developer, useful to have installed - I don't see any compiling in the solution. Unless you want to *compile* `ubuntu-desktop`?

Comment: It's required for stuff like DKMS too

Comment: @SuiciDoga: The DKMS package already depends on the necessary build tools.