# I reebooted Ubuntu 22.04.02 LTS and a command line appeared. I cannot access the desktop

Tags: command-line

I reebooted Ubuntu 22.04.02 LTS and a command line appears. I cannot access the desktop. I was trying to fix an issue with LabelImg and python 3.9 and python 3.10 before I rebooted. What should I do in order to display the desktop and have access to my files?? I tried installing the desktop with sudo apt-get but nothing was installed...

[How to start GUI from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168736/how-to-start-gui-from-command-line)

Comment: Have you changed the default `python3` version?  as Ubuntu Desktop requires the *default* python3 be unchanged... Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server however is less critical on default python3.  You'll likely fix your issue if python3 defaults are returned to normal.

Comment: I am trying this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/213678/how-to-install-x11-xorg It cannot download anything....

Comment: If you've changed the python3 default version; you'll find many Ubuntu tools don't work (*which may include `apt` too*) thus are limited to manual tools (like `wget` to download & `dpkg` to install packages instead of front-end tools like `apt` that do both but need a (default version) python3 working.  What do you see with `python3 -V` for example; if that has changed from what is expected for 22.04; Ubuntu tools that require python3 may not work correctly or work at all (*not working at all is the best/safest option actually*)

Comment: The question currently seems unanswerable due to a lack of information. "*trying ABC*" doesn't tell us what you actually did. It also does not show us complete, accurate terminal input and output that we could use to help troubleshoot.