# Cannot access GUI after restarting during python installation

Tags: command-line, 22.04, python, login

I was installing Python on Ubuntu and suddenly I was not able to find the terminal. I have then restarted the PC now facing the below interface. I am confused what to do.
[image: picture-of-tty1]
It asks for a username and password and I am confused about what to do. Please help me by reaching out.

Comment: Maybe this helps you:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/168736/how-to-start-gui-from-command-line Edit: may I ask how you installed python I mean Python should come preinstalled. My uneducated guess is that as some stuff needs Python that could have messed something up.

Comment: Did you install & change the default python3 version; as that can prevent a desktop system from working correctly; making your system a server type text terminal system - which is what your picture shows; ie. you have a login & have logged into a text only session. You should be specific as to what you actually did (*did you change the default version of python3?*) or what are you running?  Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS Desktop (*which has a GUI by default*) or Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS Server (*what you picture shows, , and can result if certain packages mistakes are made to desktop systems*)

Comment: As all Ubuntu systems include python3 by default; you'll need to tell us exactly what you mean by "*I was installing python3*", as the expected error message for that is "*is already installed*" and thus nothing is actually done... What exactly did you do? and what were you running?  Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS Desktop? or Ubuntu 22.04.3 Server?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removed Python 3 and now Ubuntu Software Center, terminal and other applications don't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/384033/removed-python-3-and-now-ubuntu-software-center-terminal-and-other-applications)